# Anylogic: Dropoff given quantity using parameters

Tags: java, anylogic

I have a train running in my model with different agents in it. At one of the stops I would like to dropoff a portion of each agent.

My agents in the train are: children, teenagers, adults and golden_oldies.
At a given stop, I would like to drop off:

20% of children

40% of teenagers

In the Drop-off agent I changed the following inputs:

**Dropoff**: Given quantity (if available)

**Quantity**: children.size(0.2) + teenagers.size(0.4)

click [**HERE**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6epq.png) to view the dropoff properties

Comment: What is your question? In what way is your code wrong? You should show your code as _text_.

Comment: In the Drop-off agent I changed the following:
Dropoff: Given quantity (if available)
Quantity: children.size(0.2) + teenagers.size(0.4)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you should create assign a value to a variable that is in the agents before the agents are picked up by your train. Create a variable called for example willBeDropped as a boolean with default value false. This variable should exist in each one of your 4 agent types.

So when the agents are picked up by the train you should assign a value of true or false to willBeDropped... So when the train gets to the given stop 20% of children will have `willBeDropped=true` and 80% will have `willBeDropped=false`.

In the dropoff you should use "while condition is true" where the condition is `agent.willBeDropped==true`

I don't know how you are picking up the passengers so I don't know how to help you there... Your question is incomplete, but you can figure that out yourself knowing what I just said.

But if you have the following configuration where everybody is being added to the train one unique time:
[image]

You can use the following code:

```
int num1=count(queue,q->q instanceof Children);
int num2=count(queue,q->q instanceof Teenager);

int numToDropOff1=(int)round(num1*0.2);
int numToDropOff2=(int)round(num2*0.4);

int counter1=0;
int counter2=0;

for(int i=0;i<queue.size();i++){
    if(counter1<= numToDropOff1 && queue.get(i) instanceof Children){
        queue.get(i).willBeDropped=true;
        counter1++;
    }else if(counter2<= numToDropOff2 && queue.get(i) instanceof Teenager){
        queue.get(i).willBeDropped=true;
        counter2++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Felipe. I am using a pickup agent thus I will be able to assign a value of willBeDropped=false in the "On enter". However, I am still uncertain as to how to dropoff exactly 20% of the children. 

Using agent.willBeDropped==true in the **dropoff** condition will release all agents with the variable and not 20%. Where/How I restrict it to 20%

Comment: Thank you Felipe. Apologies for the late reply

Comment: @ThabangMarote, mark the question as accepted if you consider that the answer may help others :)